# INSERT INTOでフォームから受け取った値を追加できない。

Tags: mysql, node.js

Nodeを使ってformタグで入力したデータをMysqlのデータベースに追加したいのですが、なんどやっても入力した文字が追加されず画面に表示されません。良ければお力添えを頂きたいです。

OS：Windouws10
node: version 1.0.0
mysql: version 2.18.1
ejs: version 2.18.i

**server.js**

```
let express = require("express")
const mysql = require('mysql')

let http = require('http')
let app = express()
let server = http.createServer(app)

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}))


const connection = mysql.createConnection({  //データベースに接続
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password : '', 
    database : 'mydb'
});

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM zatu', (error, results)=>{
        console.log(results)
           res.render('top.ejs', {zatu: results})
    })

})

app.get('/new', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('new.ejs')
})

app.post('/create', (req, res)=>{　　// 今回問題の場所
    console.log(req.body.zatuName, req.body.zatuContent)

    connection.query('INSERT INTO zatu (title) VALUES　(?)', [req.body.zatuName], 　//　ここの処理が機能していない
    (error, results)=>{
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM zatu', (error, results)=>{
            res.render('top.ejs', {zatu: results})
        })
    })
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("HelloWorld")
})
```

**top.ejs**

```
<div class="item-form-wrapper">
      <form action="/create" method="POST">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="zatuName" placeholder="雑学のタイトル">　<!-- name属性を指定している -->
        <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="ちょっとした説明"　name="zatutitle"></textarea>　<!-- なぜかtextarea内だとnameを受け取れない -->
        <input type="submit" class="button is-success is-rounded" value="投稿する">
      </form>
　　</div>
```

Comment: `console.log(req.body.zatuName, req.body.zatuContent)`は何を出力していますか？また、INSERT後の`error`の値はどのようになっていますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。こちらの質問は自己解決してしまいました。差し支えなければ<textarea>内のname＝の値がUndefindとして出力されてしまうことについて助言をいただきたいです。

Comment: 自己解決したら、その内容を回答欄に書いていただくようお願いします。新たな質問については新規チケットで質問して下さい。

Answer (score 1):

formで受け取ったreq.body~を別の変数に代入して、queryのVALUESを上記のように書き換えたらINSERTで追加することができました。

```
app.post('/create', (req, res)=>{
    var title_db = req.body.zatuTitle
    var content_db = req.body.zatuarea
    connection.query('INSERT INTO zatu (title, content) VALUES ("' + title_db + '", ' + '"' + content_db + '")', 
        (error, results)=>{
            res.redirect('/')
            console.log(error)
    })
})
```